# Problem with Intel drm in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot

I don't know what causes this, but since yesterday, my computer screen is all blank when I reboot. I could see the Ubuntu boot screen, and a few seconds later my computer just goes blank. However, I'm able to get my desktop back by switching between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

When I ran `dmesg`, I get this:

```
[9749.649010] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc set to per-chip default 
[9749.649025] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc disabled per module param
[9749.665710] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc set to per-chip default
[9749.665722] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc disabled per module param
[9749.815335] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc set to per-chip default
[9749.815354] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc disabled per module param
[9749.915133] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc set to per-chip default
[9749.915143] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc disabled per module param
[9750.081427] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc set to per-chip default
[9750.081441] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc disabled per module param 
[9750.164649] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc set to per-chip default
[9750.164664] [drm:intel_update_fbc], fbc disabled per module param
```

I have no idea what's going on. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't happen --- so I think it's worthwhile to research a bit the causes (maybe a recent upgrade? In that case a bug/regression report would be nice).

**But meanwhile, as a workaround:**

In my system too (Samsung Chronos 7 with hybrid graphics Intel/AMD), the suspend/resume if successful only if made from a virtual console. So I had to add the file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 152 Dec  7 12:09 /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt
```

(you do that by for example `sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt` and then making the script executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt`)

with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Switch to a VC before suspending and back after resume

case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
            chvt 7
        ;;
    suspend|hibernate)
            chvt 1
        ;;
esac
```

If this does not work, you can automate just the switch at resume time you are doing manually with

```
#!/bin/sh

# Switch to a VC and back after resume

case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
            chvt 1
            chvt 7
        ;;
    suspend|hibernate)
        ;;
esac
```